# Battery / Power Indicator Missing 16.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, power-management, battery

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Laptop a few days ago, and I cannot seem to get a battery / power indicator out on the gnome bar at the top.

Going through basically everything on these forums and from what I could find on google, there does not seem to be an easy fix for this.

From what I understand, (trying to fix sound too), every hardware component could be missing some drivers (not sure what to call it), and thus they are not getting recognized by the system. Could this be the case with my battery? Albeit I don't see how a battery could be needing drivers...

I have tried restarting gnome power indicator, reinstalling it, I have tried installing other power indicator applications but all in vain.

Basically I do not expect a fix to my problem, but any ideas on what to do next would be greatly appreciated.

--Tobias

---

Update:

The laptop model is: **HP Pavilion x2 Detachable (10-n182no)**. Looking around google, it seems the laptop itself does not have any support when it comes to Ubuntu.

My power options menu is the same, with and without charger, and it looks like this (you can also see the battery indicator missing on the gnome bar in the picture): [Power Indicator Missing Even Though Menu Says It Should Be There](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUCIJ.png)

Comment: Does it show up when you unplug the power adapter?

Comment: What model of laptop is it? Perhaps someone with a similar model can confirm whether they've run into this issue.

Comment: Same result with and without an adapter, updated OP with a picture that shows all my power options available at default. Also put in the name of the laptop model, but I have not been able to find anyone with the same model from google :(

Comment: On my laptop even when I unplug the AC the "When plugged in" column is still there with all the options like the battery has.